# Is there anyway to use Facebook v2.6 API instead of latest v3.0 API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

There are certain API rate limits applied on Facebook v2.7 onwards. Is there anyway I can revert back to v2.6?

Comment: Even if there was – v2.6 will be shut down on July 13, 2018, so that would only give you about a month. // The way to deal with such limits, that are introduced for a reason, is to make your app stay within them, not to try and cheat your way around it ;-)

Comment: @CBroe I just need it for testing. You got any old app?

Comment: I can’t see what you could possibly need to test in those regards.

Comment: If you got one, you can give me one for educational purposes/comparisons?

Comment: No, because I simply don’t believe you regarding the “educational purposes/comparisons” … And your comment further down, _“When I use new apps, hourly rate limit hits. But with the old apps, it doesn't. So, if you got one, could you share?”_ does not sound like you needed it “for testing” either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a deprecated API. There is no way you can use API v2.6 now.
The only possible way would be to get an old app that was created using API v2.6.

Comment: Is there anyway I can get such an old App?

Comment: There maybe some community members who got such apps. But it's not useful to build something on old apps. Building something on a deprecated API is like building a house near a volcano. :D

Comment: i am not 100% sure, but i believe selling apps for that is not allowed on facebook. it would be pointless anyway, as you can read in CBroes comment. if you really have a problem with rate limits, the only way is to reduce the number of api calls, because you are most likely doing something you are not supposed to, no matter which api version you are using.

Comment: @luschn I'll not buy. But if someone got such an app, it is probably useless anyway. So, a kind developer may just give me rights for the testing purposes.

Comment: what for? v2.6 will be gone in a few weeks.

Comment: @luschn I need it for a couple of weeks only. When I use new apps, hourly rate limit hits. But with the old apps, it doesn't. So, if you got one, could you share?

Comment: rate limits are there for a reason. think about it this way: you are doing a lot of calls, which affects performance of other users, because you want to circumvent existing api limits. always be modest with resources. we can only help you if you tell us what you want to do with the calls - the only correct way is to reduce the number of calls. maybe you just don´t need that many? what is the specific use case?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't use an older version. You have to use the latest version.

You can find this on the facebook for developers website

> An app can make calls to the version of the API that was the latest
>   available when the app was created, as well as any newer,
>   un-deprecated versions launched after the app is created.
>
> As an example, if your app was created after v2.0 was released, it
>   will be able to make calls to v2.0 until the expiration date of that
>   version, and any subsequent versions (v2.1 etc) until their expiration
>   dates.